# SQL Query that selects a column in table 1 and uses that to select sum in table 2

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables 1 with a list of employees and the group and 1 with the sales of each employee, Table 2 does not have the group number but has a list of employee names. i need to select by group number and display Name results and the total sales by name.
Table 1:

```
Name|Group
*John|1*
*Mary|2*
*Will|1*
*Jane|2*
```

Table 2

```
Name| Sale
*Will|20*
*John|10*
*Mary|10*
*Jane|20*
*John|20*
*Will|20*
*Mary|20*
```

I need the result to select group 1 and sum results by name, result should look like.
Result Table

```
Name|Sum(Sale)
*John|30*
*Will|40*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a pretty basic `JOIN` and `GROUP BY`:

```
select t2.name, sum(t2.sale)
from table2 t2 join
     table1 t1
     on t2.name = t1.name
where t1.group = 1
group by t2.name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IN` and `GROUP BY` as follows:

```
select t2.name, sum(t2.sale)
  from table2 t2 
 Where t2.name IN
     (Select t1.name from table1 t1
       where t1.group = 1)
group by t2.name
```