# Select from 1 table sum from 2 but 1 table has a AND condition

Tags: mysql, sql

Thanks for assisting with the previous query ([SQL Query that selects a column in table 1 and uses that to select sum in table 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66088829/sql-query-that-selects-a-column-in-table-1-and-uses-that-to-select-sum-in-table)) of SUM from 2 tables, I now have a additional Condition for 1 of the tables. I would like to add WHERE Group1 = 1 AND IN/OUT = 'OUT'

I have 3 tables,

1. Names ,Groups
2. Names ,Payments
3. Names ,Payments and IN/OUT

I want to only SUM the OUT Payments in Table 3, I am getting total payments only So FAR is have:

```
SELECT t1.name1, SUM(t2.sale2),SUM(t3.sale3)
FROM table1 t1 JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.name1 = t2.name2
JOIN table3 t3 ON t1.name1 = t3.name3
WHERE group1 = 1
GROUP BY t1.name1
```

i would also like to add a zero if there is no data to sum instead of removing the whole record, Currently if a name has no payments in Table 3 but has payments in table 2 it deletes the record.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the query below =>

**To Get OutPayment group by Name**

```
SELECT  t1.Names,SUM(t3.Payments) As OutPayment 
FROM TABLE3 as t3
INNER JOIN TABLE1 as t1 ON t1.Names = t3.Names
INNER JOIN TABLE2 as t2 ON t1.Names = t2.Names
WHERE t1.GroupID = 1 AND t3.INOROUT=2 --INOROUT =2 is OUT and 1 is IN
GROUP BY t1.Names;
```

**To Get TotalOutPayment**

```
SELECT  SUM(t3.Payments) As TotalOutPayment 
FROM TABLE3 as t3
INNER JOIN TABLE1 as t1 ON t1.Names = t3.Names
INNER JOIN TABLE2 as t2 ON t1.Names = t2.Names
WHERE t1.GroupID = 1 AND t3.INOROUT=2; --INOROUT =2 is OUT and 1 is IN
```

**Note:** Code is in DBFiddle too [Check the Demo Query Link](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mbecAEeQPoY6AkyXE9otK8/0)